# mysql condition statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, Arenas and Concerts.  Within Arena there is the ArenaID (primary key) and the Capacity.  In Concerts, each ConcertID (primary key) is associated with an ArenaID.  In Concerts I've got four rows.  ArenaID 1 is used twice and ArenaID 2 is used twice.

So, the thing I'm having trouble with is that I have to update Capacity (within table Arenas) to be 50,000 only on the ArenaIDs that have 2 concerts within the Concerts table.

As concisely as I can put the question: how would I update the contents of a row in one table using the contents of rows in a different table?

As far as I've gotten, I'd write a statement like

```
UPDATE Arenas SET Capacity = 50000 WHERE Concerts = 2;
```

but concerts is a column of a different table so it can't use that information.

Thanks for any help you can give me:)

Comment: Add some sample table data, before/after versions. Also show us your current code attempt.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Arenas a JOIN Concerts c ON a.ArenaID = c.ArenaID 
SET a.Capacity = 50000 WHERE c.Concerts = 2;
```

Ought to work

As a best practice though, I recommend you to explore if there is any option in MySQL like `TRANSACTION` in Sql Server, where you can do:

```
-- Make a select with the same WHERE clause as the one you'll do your update on later
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- Update Query here
-- Make an select statement corresponding to the data you have changed
```

and then see whether the update where correct, then state `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` else `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;`.

I haven't worked with MySQL in many years, so I don't know if there is any option like that, but I would imagine it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple inner join to update the records in second table:

```
UPDATE Arenas INNER JOIN Concerts ON Arenas.ArenaID = Concerts.ArenaID 
SET Arenas.Capacity = 50000 WHERE Concerts.Concerts = 2;
```

If you use alias for table names:

```
UPDATE Arenas A JOIN Concerts C ON A.ArenaID = C.ArenaID 
SET A.Capacity = 50000 WHERE C.Concerts = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use subquery to retrieve ids like this:

```
UPDATE Arenas SET capacity = 50000 where id in (SELECT arena_id FROM Concerts GROUP BY arena_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2).
```

Comment: If you're sticking DISTINCT in a GROUP BY query, something's gone very wrong somewhere.